# Combine multiple SSRS Report and publish that to SSRS native web portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

How can i combine couple of rdl reports and display that to SSRS native web portal. I already created that report and deployed to the server (SSRS Native portal) using Sql Server data tool 2015. But my client wants to view all reports in the same window. Although all reports has the same parameter.enter image description here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTizv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJg8A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSRS native web portal doesn't contain a mechanism to link multiple reports and run them on the save page via shared parameters (or anything even like that).

You have two options:

1. Create the merged report yourself.  You should be able to import (or copy/paste) the datasets from each report into a new report, link them all one one set of parameter(s), and copy paste the content of each report (then fix all broken references).
2. The option above is the naive way to merge three reports into one.  Instead, you could create a new master report, add the shared parameter and then add each additional report as a subreport to the parent report. [Tutorial here](http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/10/lesson-17-ssrs-subreports.html).
3. Create an [ASP.NET application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control) that wraps the multiple reports into a single page.  This will be quite a bit of work if you have never done this, but you would be able to create a custom parameter(s), pass the parameter(s) into the each report through code and render the multiple reports on a single page.

I would **recommend** option number 2.

Comment: I have a big issue with option 2, could you help me?